# Daily Torah from Rav Avigdor Miller

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-study, internet, avigdor-miller

Is anyone aware of any daily email that is sent out that includes a Torah from Rav Avigdor Miller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a person who puts out emails from Rav Avigdor Miller's tapes ,I beileve he also puts out such divrei Torah on paper in some shuls in Brooklyn. The email is  Torasavigdor at gmail dot com.  Its good stuff ,quick and easy read.

Comment: Does the owner of the e-mail account mind you posting the address here publicly? Consider adding a website URL that would direct one to a sign-up page to receive the e-mails, if possible.

Comment: he doesnt mind at all,it works by sending a request to that email for the emails

Comment: I just emailed him and Sam is right. He just wants you to email him at torasavigdor@gmail.com and he adds you to the list. Seems like a small time one-man operation, but once you sign up you get a daily Q and A from Rabbi Miller's Thursday night shiurim. Looks good. Thanks for the tip @sam.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a [link](http://www.simchashachaim.com/subscribe-to-simchaminute/) where you can sign up for Daily inspiration from Rabbi Avigdor Miller.

Answer (score 3):

Yes Toras Avigdor used to be a small one-man operation, but he's greatly expanded since, and has opened a fully functioning website, [TorasAvigdor.org](https://torasavigdor.org)

Comment: Hi Pinchas, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! I’ve taken the liberty of editing your post so that it actually links to the site you’ve listed; you can edit it further or roll it back if you’d like. Thanks for your answer, and I hope to see you around!

Answer (score 0):

A Moment with Rabbi Avigdor Miller Z"L weekly Q&A email http://rmillerqa.us1.list-manage.com/subscribe?u=51050d25b69193df91b43c6e8&id=ec593cbc54